# How can I stop build ParcelJS build if TypeScript compilation fails?

Tags: typescript, build, parceljs

If I write invalid TypeScript, VSCode reports the error, but ParcelJS proceeds with the build anyway.

There's a `noEmitOnError` option for either command-line `tsc` or `tsconfig.json`. However, I don't have access to the command-line and the `tsconfig.json` change is not working.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: @BenSmith, I appreciate your answer, it's close, but not quite what I need. The script I'm running is `parcel src/start.html` and it continuously watches for file system changes and reloads code automatically. I want that behavior together with TypeScript validation.

Comment: Ah I see. You didn't mention that it was for a watched build in your question! I'll do some investigation to see if I can help.

Answer (score 1):

In parcel v2+, you can use the `@parcel/validator-typescript` plugin to do this (see [docs](https://parceljs.org/languages/typescript/#experimental-validator-plugin)). Here's how:

1. Install it into your project by running `yarn add -D @parcel/validator-typescript` or `npm install -D @parcel/validator-typescript`.
2. Add a `.parcelrc` file at the root of your project with the following contents:

   ```
   {
     "extends": "@parcel/config-default",
     "validators": {
       "*.{ts,tsx}": [
         "@parcel/validator-typescript"
       ]
     }
   }
   ```
3. Make sure you have a valid `tsconfig.json` file at the root of your project, too (see [this github issue](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/4138#issuecomment-586567691)). You can generate a starter one by running `tsc --init`.

Answer (score 0):

In your package.json file, you can chain the execution of scripts.

So to stop ParcelJS from running if your TypeScript has errors you could have:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "tsc --noEmit && parcel index.html",
}
```

(Note I haven't tested this but it should work assuming your source file is index.html)

The double ampersand enables sequential execution of the scripts; use of a single ampersand would cause parallel execution.

Alternatively you could use the [run-s](https://github.com/mysticatea/npm-run-all/blob/master/docs/run-s.md) command in the [npm-run-all](https://github.com/mysticatea/npm-run-all) CLI tool e.g.

```
"scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc --noEmit && parcel index.html"
    "build": "parcel index.html",
    "tscThenBuild": "run-s tsc build",
}
```

This is useful if you want to access the scripts (i.e. for tsc and build) individually.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `tsc --noEmit` on the parcel serve script works for me. I also did some reading on this one and found this on the parcel docs:

> By default, Parcel does not perform any type checking. The recommended
> way to type check is by using an editor with TypeScript support (such
> as VSCode), and using tsc to type check your code in CI. You can
> configure this using npm scripts to run alongside your build, tests,
> and linting.
> `"check": "tsc --noEmit",`

https://parceljs.org/languages/typescript/#type-checking